# How to provide ValidationMessage For with property generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, blazor, blazor-editform

I'm generating an object at runtime to use as the EditForm model. Validation is working but I'm unsure how to set up the ValidationMessage component which requires an `Expression<Func<object>>`.

I want to provide it with a property via reflection. Something like this:

```
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => modelType.GetProperty("MyString").GetValue(model))" />
```

How can I get an Expression from an object property generated at runtime?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
<EditForm Model="@GeneratedModel" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <input @bind="TestPropBind" type="text" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private object GeneratedModel { get; set; }

    private string TestPropBind
    {
        get
        {
            PropertyInfo? propertyInfo = GeneratedModel.GetType().GetProperty("Test");
            MethodInfo? getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
            return getMethod.Invoke(GeneratedModel, new object?[0]) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyInfo? propertyInfo = GeneratedModel.GetType().GetProperty("Test");
            MethodInfo? setMethod = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();
            setMethod.Invoke(GeneratedModel, new[] { value });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    //GeneratedModel created and instantiated here at runtime
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this? [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and input components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components)

Comment: AFAIK you can't. but could you show more of your code? at least the whole EditForm part.

Comment: I suggest going for a Generic component and a base class/interface for those shared props. (basically no reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidationMessage` is a fairly simple component.  Internally it uses the `For` to build a `FieldIdentifier` object which it uses to lookup validation messages in the `EditContext's` Validation Message Store.

You can shortcut the whole reflection/expression builder process by building your own `ValidationMessage` that takes a `FieldIdentifier` as a parameter:

```cs
@foreach (var message in editContext.GetValidationMessages(Identifier))
{
    <div class="validation-message" @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes>
        @message
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public FieldIdentifier Identifier { get; set; } = new FieldIdentifier();
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(editContext);
    }
}
```

Your demo page:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using System.Reflection;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=this.model OnValidSubmit=this.OnValidSubmit >
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <span class="form-label">Value</span>
        <input class="form-control" @bind=this.model.Value />
        <MyValidationMessage Identifier=TestPropIdentifier  />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Model model = new();

    private FieldIdentifier TestPropIdentifier => new FieldIdentifier(model, "Value");

    private string TestPropBind
    {
        get
        {
            PropertyInfo? propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            MethodInfo? getMethod = propertyInfo?.GetGetMethod();
           return getMethod?.Invoke(model, new object?[0]) as string ?? string.Empty ;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyInfo? propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            MethodInfo? setMethod = propertyInfo?.GetSetMethod();
            setMethod?.Invoke(model, new[] { value });
        }
    }

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```